# Complications in integrating Silverlight and existing asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am new to silverlight, WCF RIA services. We have a medium size financial business web application. There is a lot of code. The code is well organized with lots of business objects, web controls, web forms, Data Access layer, Business logic layer.

There is a requirement for some enhancements to the web application and one of the team member wants to use silverlight to improve UI and responsiveness.

We tried to integrate a small silverlight application in the web application, But what I found is we copy the xap file and it always opens the Main form.

how can we open other silverlight controls?

How can we use the business objects and business logic with the silverlight as the silverlight supports on silverlight class library?

How can we use the existing data access library?

How can we connect to the database? I saw WCF RIA services, all the examples I saw with entity framework and we use oracle and the cannot use the beta version of oracle entity framework?

how to pass data to & from silverlight app to asp.net?

There maybe some other issues which I am unaware.

Thanks, Naveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can we open other silverlight controls?

You would create a Navigation Framework based Silverlight application.  This allows the use of a path following # in the URL to navigate to other pages within the Silverlight application.

> How can we use the business objects and business logic with the silverlight as the silverlight supports on silverlight class library?

You won't be able to use them directly.  Here you would create a Silverlight WCF service to access your business objects, you keep the business objects on the server.

> How can we use the existing data access library?

You don't, you are going via WCF to your business objects which are on the server and from there on to your data.

> How can we connect to the database? I saw WCF RIA services, all the examples I saw with entity framework and we use oracle and the cannot use the beta version of oracle entity framework?

As above, the Silverlight app only sees your specialist WCF Service.

> how to pass data to & from silverlight app to asp.net?

You can do that via your business objects and/or your new WCF Service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I open silverlight controls in other web pages(other than main.xaml)? So I can pass the business objects from server to client?

Comment: Thank you. I was able to communicate with silverlight and asp.net using WCF RIA.